# How to create a neon material using SCNMaterial in swift?

Tags: swift, scenekit, scnnode

I've been experimenting with `SCNMaterials`, focussing on emission to try and create a neon material. Not sure if it is possible, but if it could emit light, that would be great. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It's simple:

```
material.emission.contents = [NSColor greenColor];
```

all this does is make the material glow in it's own light.

If you wish to make other objects affected by this neon light,

you could add a light to your neon node like so:

```
SCNLight *mylight = [SCNLight light];
mylight.type = SCNLightTypeOmni;
mylight.color = [NSColor greenColor];
myNeonNode.light = mylight;
```

Hope that helped!

### Note:

the power of the light can be controlled by the color you use:
Dark green will seem like a green light that is not so powerful.
Light green will seem like a green light that is more powerful.

Comment: That gave the perfect effect, Thank you so much!

Comment: that is not exactly glow but self illumination. Glow is [this](https://flamesngames.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/LED-Glow-Juggling-Ball-Green.jpg), having an aura around...

Comment: Should be `material.emission.contents` (plural).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @ProBlaster, you can also set the `intensity` of the emission, not just the `contents`.

This can be useful to **animate** an object into glowing progressively more and more: Set the **contents** to a bright color from the beginning, but the **intensity** to 0:

```
material.emission.contents = UIColor.white
material.emission.intensity = 0
```

*(this will **not** glow)*

Then, in an animation block, increase the intensity to (say) 1:

```
SCNTransaction.begin()
    SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 0.5
    SCNTransaction.animationTimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeIn)
    
    material.emission.intensity = 1

SCNTransaction.commit()
```

*(Not sure you could get "automatic interpolation" of the color valued `contents` property in the animation block, like you do for the float-valued `intensity`)*